# Python3 Pandas - How to create all combinations of 4 columns and write them in rows in a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, combinations

I have 4 CSV files with one column. Each column represents a part of a name (4 parts):

**CSV 1:**

```
first_name
michael
madonna
steve
albert
```

**CSV 2:**

```
second_name
luke
han
kurt
```

**CSV 3:**

```
first_last_name
jackson
jobs
skywalker
```

**CSV 4:**

```
second_last_name
solo
cobain
einstein
```

The end result I want is to get all the possible combinations between all the 4 columns (4 CSVs):

```
first_name,second_name,first_last_name,second_last_name
michael,luke,jackson,solo
michael,luke,jackson,cobain
michael,luke,jackson,einstein
michael,luke,jobs,solo
michael,luke,jobs,cobain
michael,luke,jobs,einstein
michael,luke,skywalker,solo
michael,luke,skywalker,cobain
michael,luke,skywalker,einstein
...
```

With **pandas** I converted each **CSV** into a **dataframe** but I have no idea of how to combine all four. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import itertools
import functools

def cartesian(df1, df2):
    rows = itertools.product(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows())    
    df = pd.DataFrame(left.append(right) for (_, left), (_, right) in rows)
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = pd.read_csv('first_name.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('second_name.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('first_last_name.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('second_last_name.csv')

combined = functools.reduce(cartesian, [df1, df2, df3, df4])
combined.to_csv('combined.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product` for the heavy lifting.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

lists = [list(pd.read_csv('data{}.csv'.format(i), header=0).iloc[:,0]) for i in range(1,5)]
combined = list(','.join(items) for items in product(*lists))
pd.DataFrame(combined).to_csv('combined.csv', index=0)
```

If you just want the list form, use `combined`. It looks like:

```
['michael,luke,jackson,solo',
 'michael,luke,jackson,cobain',
 'michael,luke,jackson,einstein',
 'michael,luke,jobs,solo',
 'michael,luke,jobs,cobain',
 'michael,luke,jobs,einstein',
 'michael,luke,skywalker,solo',
 'michael,luke,skywalker,cobain',
 'michael,luke,skywalker,einstein',
 ...
```

Or the final line writes the combined values out to a CSV.